# Determine the characteristic polynomial of the matrix ...

Tags: linear-algebra, generating-functions

> Determine the characteristic polynomial of the matrix
>   $$\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\1&0&1\\\space&1&\cdot&\cdot\\\space&\space&\cdot&\cdot&\cdot\\\space&\space\space&\space\space&\space&\cdot&1\\\space&\space&\space&\space&1&0\end{bmatrix}$$

Solution:

Let, $$A^n_{\lambda}=\begin{bmatrix}-\lambda&1\\1&-\lambda&1\\\space&1&\cdot&\cdot\\\space&\space&\cdot&\cdot&\cdot\\\space&\space\space&\space\space&\space&\cdot&1\\\space&\space&\space&\space&1&-\lambda\end{bmatrix}$$

I found the recursion relation: $$A^n_{\lambda}=-\lambda A^{n-1}_{\lambda}-A^{n-2}_{\lambda}$$

I don't know how to solve recursion relations. Can someone help me? Thanks.

Comment: Look up "Chebyshev Polynomials of the second kind"